# Automate Chatter Post

Tags: community

Is there any feature in sales force that can automate posting on chatter January every year?. I tried using workflow and process but the only available schedule is Days/hrs.

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case with an example and post what you can tried

Comment: @SantanuBoral Ok sorry for that :) . Do we have any automation tool that will automatically create a chatter post every January 1st. Example use case is if Opportunity's stage is edited it will create a post on a chatter January next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution using process builder that I can think of is that you can create a 'Date/Time' field say 'PostonChatterDate' on the Opportunity. Now the date and time value of 'PostonChatterDate' field should be updated first, say to 1st Jan/2018 00:00:00. Then from process builder under schedule actions we can set
action firing time to  '1 Hour After PostonChatterDate' and add action 'Post on Chatter'. Set the entry criteria as needed.

Comment: The other option I have in my mind is to create a scheduled batch and trigger it with crontab. Thanks again.